# TFLearn LSTM Time Series Classification

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, classification, lstm, tflearn

I am trying to build an LSTM network which takes a sequence and classifies the last time step in each sequence.

This is what I have so far:

```py
#build
net = tf.input_data(shape=[None, 64, 17])
net = tf.lstm(net, 128, dropout=[.2,.8], return_seq=True)
net = tf.lstm(net, 128, dropout=[.2,.8], return_seq=True)
net = tf.lstm(net, 128, dropout=[.2,.8])
net = tf.fully_connected(net, 3, activation='softmax')
net = tf.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01, loss='categorical_crossentropy')

#train
model = tf.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=(testX,testY), show_metric=True, batch_size=None)
```

My data has been shaped into a large number of sequences with each being 64 timesteps long. each timestep has 17 features. The first sequence being timesteps 0 to 63, the second being timesteps 1 to 64, etc.

The network builds just fine, but in the fit method I get this error:

> 'ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,17) for Tensor
>   'InputData/X:0', which has shape (?,64,17)

Anyone has a suggestion as to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in your snippet, but it looks like `trainX` has the shape `(64, 17)`. If so, you should reshape it o a batch of size 1:

```
trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, 0)  # now it's [1, 64, 17]
```

The same for `testX`.